# Is there a way to create a workflow rule to create a task when members are added to a campaign?

Tags: workflow, tasks, campaign

Then when we import members through the Manage members import file, would like it to Trigger workflow rules for new and updated records.
Has anyone done this, I don't even know how to verify or insure that this rule would run.

Answer (score 3):

I was prepared to tell you that this is definitely possible, but unfortunately it doesn't appear like that is possible off of [CampaignMember](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm). So, I just went through the process of adding the workflow rule. The first step was simple and I just picked `Campaign Member`:

[image]

The second step was just as easy. I just set it up to work every time a Campaign Member is created:

[image]

And then I got to the third step where everything fell apart:

[image]

I got a bit concerned that I was losing my mind, so I took a look at a workflow rule on a different object:

[image]

Sure enough, there was the `Create Task` functionality. I did a bit of Googling, and I found a [Q&A on the Success Community](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gvLGAAY). After reading that, it all clicked. The reason it won't allow you to fire a New Task workflow on a Campaign Member is because you can't create tasks on a Campaign Member. [Tasks](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) can only be created on Accounts, Opportunities, Campaigns, Cases, or custom objects.

Comment: But if you click on any contact added to a campaign as a member you can then do a task on that contact. So would it work for the contact on the campaign?